# Getting no information from describe_images?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I want get the image id of a specific AMI. I am doing this by using boto3.describe_images.

First, I was broad and did only platform as my filter but that was too slow so I specified it to the specific ami I wanted and I got a result but it had nothing in it.

```py
client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_images(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'name',
                'Values' : [
                    'Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Base'
                ]
            }
        ]

    )
    print (response)
```

I expected a list in images but I got

```
{'Images': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '**********', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '219', 'date': '*date*', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Comment: AMI Names are normally in the format `Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base-2019.08.16`. You can use the AMIs section of the Amazon EC2 console to search for AMIs and see their typical names. (Make sure you select "Public images" otherwise you will only see your own AMIs.)

Comment: Yes, that works but is there a way I can find the most up to date image id for Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base without including the date?

Comment: If that is your goal, then I would recommend that you [Query for the Latest Windows AMI Using Systems Manager Parameter Store | AWS Management Tools Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/query-for-the-latest-windows-ami-using-systems-manager-parameter-store/).

Answer (score 0):

Few potential causes of this

1. The image does not exist in your default region. You may like to pass the region while initializing the client

   client = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='REPLACE_AMI_REGION')
2. You may be running your script using credentials of an account that is not the one where the AMI is
3. Maybe your filter is not matching with the Image
4. There is actually no AMI, hope this you have confirmed from AWS console.